# Como cargar videos en formato mp4 con webpack?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, webpack, es6

**Mi webpack.config actual**

```
const webpack           = require( 'webpack' );
const ExtractTextPlugin = require( 'extract-text-webpack-plugin' );
const PurifyCSSPlugin   = require( 'purifycss-webpack' );
const autoprefixer      = require( 'autoprefixer' );
const mqpacker          = require( 'css-mqpacker' );
const combineSelector   = require( 'postcss-combine-duplicated-selectors' );
const cssnano           = require( 'cssnano' );

// import environmental variables from our variables.env file
require( 'dotenv' ).config( { path : 'variables.env' } );

// This is JavaScript rule that specifies what to do with .js files
const javascript = {
    test    : /\.(js)$/,
    exclude : '/node_modules/',
    use     : [ { loader : 'babel-loader', query : { presets : [ 'env' ] } } ],
};

const postcss = {
    loader  : 'postcss-loader',
    options : {
        sourceMap : true,
        plugins () {
            return [
                autoprefixer( { browsers : 'last 3 versions' } ),
                mqpacker( { sort : true } ),
                combineSelector( { removeDuplicatedProperties : true } ),
                cssnano()
            ];
        }
    }
};

// this is our sass/css loader. It handles files that are
const styles = {
    test : /\.(scss)$/,
    use  : ExtractTextPlugin.extract( {
        use : process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
          ? [
              { loader : 'css-loader', options : { sourceMap : true } },
              postcss,
              {
                  loader  : 'sass-loader',
                  options : { outputStyle : 'expanded', sourceMap : true }
              }
          ]
          : [
              { loader : 'css-loader', options : { sourceMap : true } },
              {
                  loader  : 'sass-loader',
                  options : { outputStyle : 'expanded', sourceMap : true }
              }
          ]
    } )
};

const fonts = {
    test : /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
    use  : [ { loader : 'file-loader' } ]
};

const video = {
    test : /\.mp4$/,
    use  : [ { loader : 'file-loader' } ]
};

// this plugins will compress out our JS
const uglify = new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin( {
    compress : { warnings : false }
} );

const config = {
    entry   : { App : './public/javascripts/app.js' },
    stats   : { children : false },
    output  : {
        path     : `${__dirname}/public/dist`,
        filename : '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    module  : {
        rules : [
            javascript,
            styles,
            fonts
        ]
    },
    plugins : [ new ExtractTextPlugin( 'style.css' ) ]
};

if ( process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ) {
    config.plugins.push(
      uglify,
      new PurifyCSSPlugin( {
          paths         : glob.sync( [
              `${__dirname}/views/*.pug`,
              `${__dirname}/views/includes/*.pug`,
              `${__dirname}/dist/javascripts/*.js`
          ] ),
          minimize      : true,
          purifyOptions : {
              info : true,
//                rejected: true
          }
      } )
    );
}

if ( process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' )
    config.devtool = 'source-map';

process.noDeprecation = true;

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: ¿Algo que hayas intentado? Algún código o lo que sea

Comment: @MiguelMartinez Si, intente con file-loader pero no tuve éxito, estuve leyendo algo del plugin webpack-isomorphic-tools y con url-loader pero en realidad no entiendo muy bien su funcionamiento, básicamente lo que busco es cargar los videos en formato mp4 en la página, no he encontrado un loader adecuado. Actualice la pregunta con mi webpack.config actual